# captive portal keeps appearing and no internet

Tags: wireless, internet

when I try to log in to the hospital's public wifi, the login page (captive portal) keeps appearing and I can't access the internet.
it works on windows and mac.
does anyone know what I can do?

Comment: Sometimes those portals aren't compatible with Linux. There are a few things you can do. If you have an Android phone, try connect with it.Capture the portal URL with your Android device, copy it to a text file and transfer it to your Linux laptop. Copy and paste into your Linux browser. The second method is to connect with your Android device and establish USB tethering with your Linux Ubuntu laptop. Let me know if this helps and I will post a fully comprehensive answer.

Comment: I don't have an android phone but an iPhone and this doesn't work. when i use tethering it's on my mobile data. do you know another solution?

Comment: Can you get a screenshot of the hospital's captive portal including the URL if displayed, on your Ubuntu device?

Comment: yes i can but i can't upload it to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Captive Portals are... finnicky.  Sometimes, those portals don't like Linux, and I proved this myself a couple of weeks ago when I was in hospital for appendicitis and getting my appendix removed.

Unfortunately, if a captive portal won't accept your clicks or anything, and you've tried more than one browser (Chrome and Firefox are the big ones), AND it keeps appearing (or just doesn't load) then your only bet you have left for using the Internet is to tether to your phone or such.

Unfortunately, these captive portals are *not* actually your system and we can't actually do much do diagnose/fix those.  (So the best we can do is offer alternatives)